# exec from regex returns null

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my code snippet:

```js
var myString = '#EXTINF:-1 group-title="|FR| CHAINES FRANÇAISES |FR|",|FR|*****CANALSAT*****|FR|';
var group_title = /(group-title=")(\S*)["]/;
var matchgroup_title = group_title.exec(myString);
console.log(matchgroup_title);
```

I am not familiar to regex so I can't understand this code. Why does exec here return null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exists because of `\S*`. If you pop it into [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KhOBO1/1), you'll see:

[image]

So, `\s*` will match any non-whitespace character, and **a space is considered a whitespace character**, so this does not match. You can simply use `[^"]` to check for anything that isn't another quote.

You can simplify this to:

```js
var myString = '#EXTINF:-1 group-title="|FR| CHAINES FRANÇAISES |FR|",|FR|*****CANALSAT*****|FR|';
var group_title = /group-title="([^"]+)"/;
var matchgroup_title = group_title.exec(myString);
console.log(matchgroup_title);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`(group-title=")` matches `group-title="`

`(\S*)` matches zero or more non-whitespace characters, so `|FR|`

`["]` then matches a `"`, but there isn't one (well, there is, but there are whitespace characters first, so no match).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wanted to get 'group-title="|FR| CHAINES FRANÇAISES |FR|" exactly.